# Why is classical geometry usually not taught in universities?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, contest-math

I've observed that much of the world introduces a bit of geometry to students in high school and then just leaves it right there. For instance, you don't learn even 1/2 of what is needed (in terms of facts and theorems) for Olympiad type problems in geometry.

Now I know that not everyone is going to attempt Olympiad problems but, what I've observed is that it is possible to go from Bachelor all the way to PhD in math even in pretty good schools and be all but totally lost when looking at Olympiad problems.

This rings especially true when students in university math departments can be found to know next to nothing (except vague recollections of stuff about triangles and circles maybe) about classical geometry and they often have no chance to fill that gap because most math departments don't offer courses like that anymore.

$\textbf{Question}$: Why is this?

I get that number theory and combinatorics at least are still offered (although just as electives). But as far as I can tell, it seems like some areas of math have been quarantined to the Olympiad world pretty much.

Comment: There is a "Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry" course offered at my university.

Comment: Once one has [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry) and [algebraic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry) geometry (and the fairly powerful, semi-automatic solution techniques coming from them), there is very little *geometric* reason to study [synthetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_geometry) geometry.  There could be value in studying synthetic geometry for practice with axiomatization and proof writing, but there are much more directly applicable subject matters (real analysis, abstract algebra, et al.) for doing so.

Comment: I editted the tags, in particular, this is a soft question, so I added that tag.

Comment: A math department looking to churn out PhDs probably finds it to be a more efficient use of its resources to teach courses where theory is built. And then challenge their students' proficiency via the homework and exam exercises. That certainly does not mean that there aren't many students who are motivated by Olympiad/Putnam style comps. There infact certainly are, and IME it is supported. Success in contest math typically isn't a core mission for the math departments though. These students are also generally motivated enough to work on contest math independently too.

Comment: If you are a math major at a US university, you will have a chance to take a class where at least some classical geometry is taught. But many students opt not to take such a class and instead take a class in statistic or numerical analysis or financial math.... Can you really blame them?

Comment: While my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745996/how-much-classical-geometry-must-a-geometer-know/1748439#1748439) primarily deals with classical geometry at the graduate level, it is still relevant to your question.

Comment: Isn't it better to ask why the writers of Olympiad problems insist on including these kinds of problems than to ask why universities don't prepare students for Olympiad-style problems? The former question probably has a reasonable answer. My instinctive answer to the latter question would be simply: why would they? Certainly "classical geometry" is far from the only branch of mathematics which used to be prominent but isn't any more.

Comment: The [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com) and/or [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com) stacks might be good (better?) places for this question.

Comment: Strongly related: [Why are the contents of contest maths so different from contents of degree-level maths?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/16858/745)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about the Olympiad or Putnam world (at least not since my own undergrad days a long long time ago). But I'll answer the title question from a different point of view.

I think there's still quite a lot that a low-to-mid level undergraduate geometry class can still offer even to students who intend to pursue a graduate degree in mathematics.

One way to teach such a class (alluded in the comment of @Mason) is to emphasize the 2000 year quest to resolve whether the "parallel postulate" is independent of the other axioms. This quest culminated in the 19th discovery of hyperbolic geometry. Knowledge of the three basic 2-dimensional geometries --- Euclidean, hyperbolic spherical --- is an essential first example of the modern approach to classifying geometries.

Classical Euclidean geometry does not have to be taught in the classical method. For example, there are books in Euclidean geomety which argue that Euclid's book carefully avoids symmetry arguments and therefore their book is going to avoid symmetry arguments in their book. I find this to be an unfortunate pedagogical choice. Instead, another way that I teach axiomatic Euclidean geometry (which remains an excellent introduction to axiomatic methods in mathematics) is by a method which embraces symmetry, building it into the axiomatic approach. I then go on to build up to the classification of the 17 wallpaper groups, which is a great way to introduce some group theory. In fact, in my upcoming graduate course in geometric group theory, I intend to give a summary of the whole semester of that undergrad course, including the classification of wallpaper groups, before moving on to more modern geometric classification theorems.

Answer (score 0):

This expands upon my comment, and also relates to what you said about Math Olympiads and Putnam Exams. Now, solving a good mathematical puzzle is a lot of fun, and if you are proficient at it, then it could only help the rest of your mathematical career. For every contest math problem though, someone has the answer already--namely, at least the person who came up with it. And there isn't much value to Science in answering questions that have already been answered by someone else. The idea instead is to be the first one to solve an open problem. That is what advances the frontier of knowledge.

So the focus of PhD programs in math departments is to prepare students for research. This generally means teaching the theory, complete w good homework and exam questions to challenge the students' knowledge and creativity. Now, I am not sure how much research is left to be done in classical geometry. If there is, I do believe it that it is being studied in the *applied* mathematics department. The combinatorialists seem to love applying the tools they develop to other areas of mathematics and maybe this includes classical geometry. I am not positive of this though.

Now, on the other hand, if you are interested in a career as a quant analyst, then being proficient in solving mathematics puzzles is a trait that will serve you well, especially through the interview process, where you will be given a puzzle to solve on the spot. In that case, practicing on old Olympiad or Putnam puzzles may be a smart thing to sprnd a lot of time focusing on.